# SQL - UPDATE not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

When i run this query ;

```
UPDATE dbo.Account
SET new_AccountTypeIdName  =  IIF(new_Existing = 1 , 'Existing','Potential')
Where new_AccountTypeIdName = 'Member' 
AND new_Existing IN (0,1)
```

It just changes anything that is    `new_AccountTypeIdName =    'Member' to 'Existing', No matter if 'new_existing = 1 or 0'.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
im using sql server 2012

Thanks

Comment: Run this: `SELECT * FROM Account WHERE new_AccountTypeIdName = 'Member' AND new_Existing IN (0,1)` to see the expected rows for update. I suspect there will be blank result.

Comment: @i486 , I ran your query and i got results

Answer (score 1):

Split your query to 2 simple:

```
UPDATE dbo.Account
  SET new_AccountTypeIdName  =  'Existing'
    Where new_AccountTypeIdName = 'Member' AND new_Existing = 1

UPDATE dbo.Account
  SET new_AccountTypeIdName  =  'Potential'
    Where new_AccountTypeIdName = 'Member' AND new_Existing = 0
```

Comment: Same result?  when i view in on CRM Online

Comment: "same result" - i.e. only one of queries is working?

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
UPDATE dbo.Account
SET new_AccountTypeIdName  =  case when new_Existing = 1 then 'Existing' else 'Potential' end
Where new_AccountTypeIdName = 'Member' 
AND new_Existing IN (0,1)
```

Comment: I ran your query same result , it only says it has affected one row, but all rows with Farmer were affected?

Comment: Then check your data and condition

Comment: While this code may solve the OP's problem, a few words of explanation would go a long way to making this answer more understandable for everyone.